# Converting *.lyr file to shapefile or raster using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, layers

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10 and Python 2.6.5.

i have created a "test.lyr" file, now i want to convert it either to shape file or raster file. i have created the "test.lyr" from "test0.tif" and added symbology from "test0.lyr" files as follows.

```
 arcpy.MakeRasterLayer_management(tifFile,tmpFile,"#","","#")
 arcpy.SaveToLayerFile_management(tmpFile,curFile)
 arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management(curFile,symbologyLayer)
```

the curFile in the above code is the test.lyr file obtained.

Can anyone show how to convert it to "test1.shp" or "test1.tif" file using arcpy?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Feature Class to Shapefile geoprocessing tool to convert a lyr to a shp (see code example below).

```
BASEMAP_LOADER_Counties_lyr = "C:\\Temp\\BASEMAP.LOADER.Counties.lyr"
Temp__2_ = "C:\\Temp"

# Process: Feature Class To Shapefile (multiple)...
gp.FeatureClassToShapefile_conversion("C:\\Temp\\BASEMAP.LOADER.Counties.lyr", Temp__2_)
```

And you can use the Feature to Raster tool to convert a lyr to raster (see code sample below).

```
Feature_2_tif = "C:\\Temp\\Feature_2.tif"
BASEMAP_LOADER_Counties_lyr__2_ = "C:\\Temp\\BASEMAP.LOADER.Counties.lyr"

# Process: Feature to Raster...
gp.FeatureToRaster_conversion(BASEMAP_LOADER_Counties_lyr__2_, "OBJECTID", Feature_2_tif, "4832.40368")
```

Comment: hi both arcpy.FeatureClassToShapefile_conversion and arcpy.FeatureToRaster_conversion did not work...

Comment: in most of the cases it says: The value is not a Feature Layer. i opened my a.lyr file with arcmap 10, it shows everything fine...

Comment: for the shapefile conversion exactly it says the following: ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000840: The value is not a Feature Layer.
Failed to execute (FeatureClassToShapefile).

Comment: @thm, My two examples were from using ArcGIS 9.3.1.  What happens if you try another different lyr using both tools, same error?

Comment: The OPs input data is not a featureclass layer, it's  raster layer - *i have created the "test.lyr" from "test0.tif"*

Answer (score 0):

I converted a polygon KML to a layer by KMLtoLayer in ArcGIS 10.5... I only could convert this layer to shp by the following procedure:

```
# Final shp path (Example)
shape_path = r'E:\40\00_SOL_PONTUAIS\20200922_Rangel_Consalter_REGULADOR\SHP\teste.shp'

# setting workspace
arcpy.env.workspace = r'D:\' # folder where u saved your layer

# Converting to shapefile
arcpy.FeatureToPolygon_management(r'LAYER_NAME\Polygons',
                                  shape_path, '#', 'ATTRIBUTES', '#')
### OBS --> replace 'LAYER_NAME' be the name of your layer name
```